# Finding maxima and minima with the function filter() in RStudio

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to find a way to extract the maximum and minimum of the variable 'population' from gapminder with the `filter()` function. The name of the data frame is 'gap'.

The clue the exercise give me is:

```
filter (___ == max (____))
```

And for the function not to return `NA`, it must include the argument `na.rm = TRUE`

What I have tried without success is:

```
filter(population == max (gap$population, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: You don't need the `gap$`. Presumably you want something like `gap %>% filter(population == max(population))` or `filter(gap, population == max(population))`.

Comment: Is this filter from dplyr or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, the filter is from dplyr.